# What does the "Integer" in "Integer.parseInt()" do?

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to Java so this question might sound stupid.
I understand calling a method using an object:

```
Foo obj = new Foo();
obj.method();
```

But I don't understand the syntax for `Integer.parseInt()` or `Character.isDigit()`. What do the prefixes do in these cases? Is there any similarity between this and calling a method using an object of its class?

Comment: [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) is a class. It is the [wrapper-class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) for the primitive `int`.

Comment: it is a static method, you don't need an instance to call it, so just the class name  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods

Comment: @Turing85 Oh! So it is a static method defined for the class Integer?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is.

Comment: It is a `static` method belonging to the class called `Integer`. Static methods belong to the class itself, not to instances/objects of it. So you call it on the class, `Foo.bar()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, `Character`, ... are classes for the primitive types `int`, `float`, `double`, `char`, ... and each of them have some predefined methods to use.

In this case `parseInt()` method takes an `String` as input and converts it into its equivalent integer. for more description take a look at [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-integer-class-java/).

[Here is the Original documentation for it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Answer (score 0):

## Scenario

Let's imagine we want to parse a `String` into an `int`:

#### The Wrong Way

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String asString = "1";
  int asNumber = parseInt(asString); // Error
  System.out.println(asNumber);
}
```

In this scenario we (and the compiler) don't know how the owner of the method `parseInt` is and don't know the logic to execute.

#### The Correct Way

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String asString = "1";
  int asNumber = Integer.parseInt(asString); // Correct
  System.out.println(asNumber);
}
```

Now, we (and the compiler) know that the method `parseInt` is declared on `Integer`.

## Syntax

You are already familiar with calling method on an instance of a class (`obj.method()`).

The difference to `Integer.parseInt()` is, that we do not need to create an instance of `Integer` to call the method `parseInt` because it is a [*static method*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

```java
public class Integer {

  public static parseInt(String value) { /* ... */ }

}
```

A method or variable that is declared with `static` is a *class member* instead of a *instance member*. Class members are accessed by `ClassName.member`.